# Загрузка файла на сервер CloseableHttpClient Java

Tags: java, http, fileupload, httpclient

Программа должна загрузить файл в определенную папку на хостинге

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Upload {

public static void testUpload4() throws Exception {


        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new     HttpPost("http://domain.com/www/import2");

            FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("D:/yandex_yml2.xml"));

            HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("yandex_yml2.xml", bin)
                    .build();

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("строка состояния: " + response.getStatusLine()); //получаем строку состояния
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаю

```
public class Hello {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Upload.testUpload4();
}
}
```

Результат:

```
executing request POST http://domain.com/www/import2 HTTP/1.1
----------------------------------------
строка состояния: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Response content length: -1
```

Не могу разобраться в чем причина, почему файл не загружается. подскажите, плиз...

Comment: А на какой хостинг вы его загружается?

Comment: хостинг https://www.ukraine.com.ua/
а разве это может влиять?

Comment: В коде у вас другое написано